# Counting polygons with multiple filters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point-in-polygon, aggregate, qgsexpression

I am using the aggregate expression in QGIS to count how often my polygon name appears in another point layer. The *'Polygon_zone_name'* exists on both my polygon layer and my points layer, I can successfully count how many times it exists, but I need an additional filter to only count where the attribute field `"Materials_Count" = 1` in my point layer. Can't see to get it to work.

```
aggregate(
    'Polygon_layer',
    'count',
    Polygon_Zone_name,
    Polygon_Zone_name=attribute(@parent, 'Polygon_Zone_name')
        AND attribute(targetlayer, Materials_Count='1')
    )
```

Comment: Do I need to reference the layer target again?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you have:

- A polygon layer called `Polygon_layer`. It has one string attribute called `Polygon_zone_name`.
- A point layer called `targetlayer`. It has one string attribute called `Polygon_zone_name` which has identical strings as the polygon layer has in a field named the same. Additionally, this layer has an integer attribute called `Materials_Count`.

You now want to add the count of appearances of the string in `Polygon_Zone_name` of the `Polygon_layer` to the `targetlayer` if both `Polygon_Zone_name` strings are identical and the `targetlayer`s attribute `Materials_Count` is 1.

If that is correct, try this expression:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='Polygon_layer',
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:="Polygon_Zone_name",
    filter:="Polygon_Zone_name"=attribute(@parent, 'Polygon_Zone_name')
        AND attribute(@parent, 'Materials_Count')=1
    )
```

Comment: Thats worked!! thank you